# How To Find Component With Variable Name in Ext.js?

Tags: extjs, frontend, component-query

I want to get component and its disable/visible value.

Example:

```
this.btnForm = new baseComponent.menuItem({
        text: 'Form',
        disabled: true
    });

var btnName;
```

I want to get btnForm's disabled value by btnName.
How can I do with ComponentQuery or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get btnForm's disabled value by btnName striaghtaway using the config name itself! You can use *this.btnForm.disabled* or *this.btnForm.isDisabled()* which will return the button's disabled value! ComponentQuery in Ext JS does not directly provide a way to access components using their variable names. ComponentQuery is primarily based on selectors that target properties like xtype, itemId, or CSS classes.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        // Creating component
        this.btnForm = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            text: 'Button',
            disabled: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        
        var btnName = this.btnForm.disabled;
        console.log(btnName)
    }
});
```